# mvc3 how can I reuse my actionResult code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reusability

Hello everyone as you can tell my still learning, I was wondering how or what is the best method to use in order to reuse my code for database actions  ;for instance with the code below

```
   // i reuse this code multiple times throughout my site but everytime I change it I must change
 // all of the different Edit's each time I would like a central hub for all of it.
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {



        var ss = User.Identity.Name;
        int myid = Convert.ToInt32(ss);
        var buyer = (from s in db.buyers where myid == s.RegistrationID select s).FirstOrDefault();


        ViewBag.RegistrationID = myid;

        if (buyer != null && buyer.RegistrationID == myid)
        {

            return View(buyer);
        }
        else
        {
            RedirectToAction("buyerrequire");

        }
        return View("buyerrequire");
    }
```

How can I put such code into a reusable container? so that if I change something there it will change all over that website where that container is used, **sortoff like a _Partial except for ActionResults** ... thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing that. 
1. You can have another base Controller for this purpose as follows:

```
public class SomeController : Controller{
  // the code you use in multiple places.
}
```

Then the controllers which need these code, can extend this Controller.

1. You can have an `[Attribute]` for this functionality and you can decorate the methods with this attribute.

I would go for 2, this is also what asp.net mvc uses for common code such as attributes, logging, security etc.